# How to write a kernel for pytorch convolution function?

Tags: python, pytorch, convolution

I want to make convolution of matrix

```
np.random.seed(0)
m_numpy = np.random.choice([0,1],p=(0.5,0.5),size=(6,6))
m = torch.from_numpy(Z_numpy).type(torch.FloatTensor)
```

```
tensor([[1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
        [0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
        [0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.]])
```

with kernel:

```
krnl = torch.tensor([[1,1,1],
                            [1,0,1],
                            [1,1,1]])

krnl
```

```
tensor([[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]])
```

However using function `conv2d` from `torch.nn.functional` I don't see where to write those tensors in it. Doing this `conv2d(m, krnl,mode='same')` brings error:

```
TypeError: conv2d() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (Tensor, Tensor, mode=str), but expected one of:
 * (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, tuple of ints padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
 * (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, str padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
```

How to do that?

Comment: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/setting-custom-kernel-for-cnn-in-pytorch/27176 Does this help ?

Answer (score 1):

Both the weight tensor and the input tensor must be four-dimensional:

- The shape of the input tensor is `(batch_size, n_channels, height, width)`. Here you are looking to infer from a single-channel `6x6` instance, *i.e.* a shape of `(1, 1, 6, 6)`.
- The shape of the weight tensor provided to [`F.conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.conv2d.html) corresponds to `(n_filters, n_channels, kernel_height, kernel_width)`. In your case it seems you only have a single filter with a single channel, with `kernel_height` and `kernel_width` both equal to `3`.

Also, both operands must have a *dtype* of *float*.

```
>>> krnl = tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
                   [1., 0., 1.],
                   [1., 1., 1.]])

>>> F.conv2d(m.reshape(1,1,*m.shape), krnl.reshape(1,1,*krnl.shape), padding='same')
tensor([[[[2., 4., 4., 3., 4., 2.],
          [5., 6., 5., 4., 4., 3.],
          [4., 6., 6., 4., 5., 3.],
          [4., 5., 5., 3., 5., 2.],
          [4., 4., 7., 4., 5., 3.],
          [2., 1., 4., 2., 4., 1.]]]])
```

Alternatively, to reshape to `(1, 1, h, w)`, you could do:

```
>>> F.conv2d(m[None, None], krnl[None, None], padding='same')
# yields the same result
```

<sub>With `import torch.nn.functional as F`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In the below code I've changes the dimesions of `m_numpy` to `(1,1,6,6)`, `Conv2d` expects this dimension, then matched the `kernel` dimesnion as well, used the functional module's conv2d as described in [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/setting-custom-kernel-for-cnn-in-pytorch/27176)

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

np.random.seed(0)
m_numpy = np.random.choice([0,1],p=(0.5,0.5),size=(1,1,6,6))
m = torch.from_numpy(m_numpy).type(torch.FloatTensor)

print(m)

weights = torch.tensor([[[[1.,1.,1.],
                          [1.,0.,1.],
                          [1.,1.,1.]]]])

print(weights)

output = F.conv2d(m, weights, padding = 1)

print(output)
```

Gives output

```
tensor([[[[1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
          [0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
          [0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
          [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.]]]])
tensor([[[[1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 0., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1.]]]])
tensor([[[[2., 4., 4., 3., 4., 2.],
          [5., 6., 5., 4., 4., 3.],
          [4., 6., 6., 4., 5., 3.],
          [4., 5., 5., 3., 5., 2.],
          [4., 4., 7., 4., 5., 3.],
          [2., 1., 4., 2., 4., 1.]]]])
```